# Php Button Submittion not working for me

Tags: php

I wanted this to echo, "Button clicked" when the button is clicked. But that's not happening. How can I make it work the way I want it to?(Cut out majority of the code)

```
<?php include("./Assets/Inc/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?php
//Variable declaring
    $reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//Checking if registry info valid
   if($reg){ //If register button submitted
        echo'Button clicked';
   }
   else
   {
        echo'nothing...';
   }
?>

        <div class="signup">
            <form id="signupinfo">
                <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo out the value in `$_POST['reg']` to make sure the form is properly posting information to your script?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@` from `@$_POST['reg'];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are submitting an empty form, but you do not have a method on your form so it is not being added to the $_POST array, - also you are not closing your input. Try the following:

```
    <form id="signupinfo" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!" />
    </form>
```

However this relies on the form being submitted to the same page so that on the subsequent re-load - $reg has been set and echos - but there are better ways of doing it  than this.

EDIT: also wondering why you are using the "@" symbol - this suppresses warnings and error messages so will not allow you to see what error is generated and therefore what needs to be fixed. Tye the same code but without the @:

```
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
```

Comment: @peter Thank you so so so much! The form actually has information, but I cut it off to make the post short and easy to go through.